# Reset password on Realm without having a server

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

I'm working on an iOS only application and use Realm as the Database.
I played around and set up a mongo db instance and the sync works and everything is fine **except** the password reset functionality.
I have two options (as can be read [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/authentication/email-password/#std-label-email-password-authentication-password-resets)) to reset the password:

1. a client side function
2. sending a reset-password mail

I don't want to use 1. as it would need another service to send any kind of token to confirm the user is actually connected to the account.
For 2. I need my own server to either implement the password reset there or store a certificate which would redirect the user to the application. Well, I don't have a server.

For clarification: You need to send the reset-password email with a reset-password url which has no default value:

[image: MongoDB options for the send mail]
Question: What other options do I have? Why isn't there a base URL provided by mongoDB to reset the users password like Firebase is doing it? Has anybody run into that problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: Hmm. I may be misunderstanding the comments in the question for points 1 and 2. There are a bunch of options for 1, including *You define a Function for App Services to run when you callResetPasswordFunction() in the SDK*. But really, 2 is a simple solution - *App Services sends a Password Reset URL to a user's email address*. Why don't you use 2? [Send a Password Reset Email](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/authentication/email-password/#send-a-password-reset-email)

Comment: Because I don’t have a sever which the reset email could point to.

Comment: Um *App Services sends a Password Reset URL to a user's email address.* note **to a user's email address** - not to a server

Comment: I updated the question to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: With iOS apps, it's generally a good practice to use in-app confirmations. *Mobile applications can handle email confirmation directly in the app. To do this, configure [universal links](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)* When a user clicks the link in their email, it opens in your app. You can get a basic website pretty easily as well. Additionally, you can use Facebook, Google or Apple authentication as well who provide thier own reset resources.

Comment: Yes, I guess I’ll go for the Google/apple Authentication which seems to be the easiest way. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn’t any  default behaviour provided by MongoDB which is very unfortunate.
The solutions I have found are:

A) uses third party authentication provider (like Google Firebase), create the accounts there and use the JWT Token to log in users to MongoDB.

B) omit the email verification and only stick to login providers like Google, apple or meta.